# How can I trace iPhone DEVICES using Google Map?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios9, tracking

Is it possible to trace iPhone devices using Google map in i OS ? This is seem like I have to work on iPhone as well Web site. I have some Idea but not very clear. I have to configure my app my with map.

Comment: Too broad a question. Explain what you know and what you'd like to know more about. [This](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/) should give you an idea to start with.

Comment: like when ever user turn on the option (turn on GPS). CLLocationManager Will send the current latitude and longitude to the server side and google map trace the latitude and longitude.